# How do I code my userform to insert the specified number of rows beneath the selected cell?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a userform that I've created that first asks how many rows I would like to insert. The next part of the userform asks what values I would like in columns 1 and 32 of each newly created row (I've set it up so that a maximum of 6 new rows can be created at one time). My data has 45 columns, and the only data that I want to change in the newly created rows is the data in the two columns i said earlier (1 and 32). I want the data from all the other columns from the original row to be copied down into each new row. My problem is that I can't seem to figure out how to write a code that will do this the way I want it. To provide an example, if I respond to the userform that I want to add 3 rows below the currently active cell, it will then ask me what values i want to enter for columns 1 and 32 for each of these new rows. So I would enter something like this:

**First New Row**
Column 1: 8/17/2019
Column 32: 400

**Second New Row**
Column 1: 8/10/2019
Column 32: 500

**Third New Row**
Column 1: 8/3/2019
Column 32: 600

I've tried many different codes but I've only really figured out how to write it so that it inserts one row below the active cell and its completely blank, I don't know how to program it so that it enters he values I selected for columns 1 and 32 and copies all other data down from the original row. I've figured out the code for the clear and cancel button on my userform already, I am now only concerned with writing this code for the "OK" button.

```
Private Sub CancelButton_Click()

    Unload Me

End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub ClearButton_Click()

    Call UserForm_Initialize

End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub OKButton_Click()

    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lRsp As Long

    On Error Resume Next

    lRow = Selection.Row()
    lRsp = MsgBox("Insert New row above " & lRow & "?", _
            vbQuestion + vbYesNo)
    If lRsp <> vbYes Then Exit Sub

    Rows(lRow).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Rows(lRow + 1).Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Rows(lRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone

End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    AddRowsTextBox.Value = ""

    Date1TextBox.Value = ""
    Date2TextBox.Value = ""
    Date3TextBox.Value = ""
    Date4TextBox.Value = ""
    Date5TextBox.Value = ""
    Date6TextBox.Value = ""

    Qty1TextBox.Value = ""
    Qty2TextBox.Value = ""
    Qty3TextBox.Value = ""
    Qty4TextBox.Value = ""
    Qty5TextBox.Value = ""
    Qty6TextBox.Value = ""


End Sub
```

Comment: Just a friendly suggestion, don't use `Select` for the copy and insert.  Set the `Set Rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(x).Rows(lRow)` you want and then `Range.Copy(Rng)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what i understand from your requirement, I would have add one more spin button on the form to make it user friendly. It may look like this.

[image]

User form Code may please be modified according to control names in your form

```
Option Explicit
Public Bal As Double, XQnty As Double, LargeOrder As Double, Sm As Double
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim lRow As Long
Dim lRsp As Long

lRow = ActiveCell.Row()
lRsp = MsgBox("Insert New row Below " & lRow & "?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo)


If lRsp <> vbYes Then Exit Sub
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim R As Long, i As Integer, RowtoAdd As Integer
Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
RowtoAdd = Me.SpinButton1.Value
R = ActiveCell.Row
  With Ws
        .Cells(R, 32).Value = LargeOrder
        For i = 1 To RowtoAdd
        .Cells(R + 1, 1).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
        .Cells(R, 1).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=.Cells(R + 1, 1)
        .Cells(R + 1, 1).Value = Me.Controls("TextBox" & i).Value
        .Cells(R + 1, 32).Value = Me.Controls("TextBox" & 7 + i).Value
        R = R + 1
        Next i
  End With
Unload Me
End Sub
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Unload Me
End Sub
Private Sub SpinButton1_Change()
Dim x As Integer, i As Integer, Y As Double
Me.TextBox7.Value = Me.SpinButton1.Value
x = Me.SpinButton1.Value
Sm = 0
    For i = 1 To 6
    Me.Controls("TextBox" & i).BackColor = IIf(i <= x, RGB(255, 100, 100), RGB(255, 2550, 255))
    Me.Controls("TextBox" & i + 7).Value = IIf(i <= x, Int(Bal / x), 0)
    Sm = Sm + IIf(i <= x, Int(Bal / x), 0)
    Next

    If Sm <> Bal Then
    Me.TextBox8.Value = Int(Bal / x) + Bal - Sm
    End If
ManualBal
End Sub
Private Sub TB_LO_Change()
LargeOrder = Val(Me.TB_LO.Value)
Bal = XQnty - LargeOrder
ManualBal
End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim i As Integer, dx As Variant
Me.SpinButton1.Value = 1
Me.TextBox7.Value = 1
Me.TextBox1.BackColor = RGB(255, 100, 100)
dx = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1).Value
XQnty = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 32).Value
LargeOrder = 575
Bal = XQnty - LargeOrder
Sm = 0
If IsDate(dx) = False Then dx = Now()
    For i = 1 To 6
    Me.Controls("TextBox" & i).Value = Format(dx - i * 7, "mm-dd-yyyy")
    Sm = Sm + Int(Bal / 6)
    Me.Controls("TextBox" & i + 7).Value = Int(Bal / 6)
    Next
    If Sm <> Bal Then
    Me.TextBox8.Value = Int(Bal / 6) + Bal - Sm
    End If
Me.TB_LO = LargeOrder
Me.TB_Bal = 0
End Sub
Private Sub ManualBal()
Dim x As Integer, i As Integer
x = Me.SpinButton1.Value
Bal = XQnty - LargeOrder
Sm = 0
    For i = 1 To 6  ' Or may use 6 insted of X
    Sm = Sm + Val(Me.Controls("TextBox" & i + 7).Value)
    Next
    Me.TB_Bal.Value = Bal - Sm
End Sub
Private Sub TextBox8_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
ManualBal
End Sub
Private Sub TextBox9_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
ManualBal
End Sub
Private Sub TextBox10_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
ManualBal
End Sub
Private Sub TextBox11_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
ManualBal
End Sub
Private Sub TextBox12_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
ManualBal
End Sub
Private Sub TextBox13_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
ManualBal
End Sub
```

Here Text Box 1 to 6 for dates, 7 for Spin Button  values and Text Box 8 to 13 for quantity. May please either modify code according to control names Or modify Control names according to code.

Edit: Two new Text Box added named `TB_BAL`  to show when entering values in manually in Quantity text boxes (balance calculated only at exit event of text boxes) and `TB_LO` to change `LargeOrder` during run.

Comment: This is incredible, it works perfectly. I can't thank you enough. I did have one last question though. Is there anything I can add to the code that would recognize the quantity in the original row so that when I add the new rows below it, the quantity from the original row changes to the balance of what it originally was minus the quantities I entered for the new rows?

Comment: @jake You made my day. I actually thought this, while preparing the answer but refrained go beyond scope of question. I will come back with it again. However meanwhile you may work with idea below. Take `ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 32).Value` to some variable (may be double).in the Initialize event. Then get balance by subtracting `Larageorder`. Each text box quantity may be calculated as int(Balance/6). and one text box (may be last would be  balance- summation of five of text box. Then repeat the  process in Change event of Spin button for spin button value instead of 6..

Comment: edited answer.  Pl feedback along with inserting rows this will replace the existing line quantity with `LargeOrder`. Also `TB_LO`  added to modify `LargeOrder` in run time and `TB_Bal` to view balance when entering quantity manually.

Comment: I really like the way that you set this up, unfortunately when I clicked "OK" on the userform and checked to see if the quantity on my original row had changed to the value i entered in the form, it had not. I'm gonna play around with it for a little while to see if I can get it to work though.

Comment: I figured it out! All I had to do was add this to the code for command button1.      With Ws
  ActiveCell.Value = Me.TB_OriginalQty.Value
  End With.              Thank you again for your help